# Authorize.net after payment status is showing voided

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am facing issue, when i do payment from Authorize.net.. Payment is done successfully, but when I go to Authorize.net website and check status there, it shows the status Authorize.net and get this message.

This is the code i am using:

```
include("authorizenet_functions.php");

$payment_first_name=$_POST['payment_first_name'];
$payment_last_name=$_POST['payment_last_name'];
$payment_address01=$_POST['payment_address01'];
$payment_address02=$_POST['payment_address02'];
$payment_city=$_POST['payment_city'];
$payment_state=$_POST['payment_alabama'];
$payment_zipcode=$_POST['payment_zipcode'];
$payment_phone_number=$_POST['payment_phone_number'];
$card_number=$_POST['payment_email'];
$payment_date=$_POST['payment_date'];
$payment_year=$_POST['payment_year'];
$card_exp_date=$payment_date.'-'.$payment_year;
$cvv=$_POST['payment_gender'];
$subscription_amount = '14.99';

            if($transaction_mode=="T")
            {
            $post_url = "https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
            $test_request = "TRUE";
            }
            else
            {
            $post_url = "https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
            $test_request = "FALSE";
            }

            $post_values = array(       
            // the API Login ID and Transaction Key must be replaced with valid values
            "x_login"           => $loginname,
            "x_tran_key"        => $transactionkey,         
            "x_version"         => "3.1",
            "x_delim_data"      => "TRUE",
            "x_delim_char"      => "|",
            "x_relay_response"  => "FALSE", 
            "x_type"            => "AUTH_ONLY",
            "x_method"          => "CC",
            "x_card_num"        => $card_number,
            "x_card_code"       => $cvv,
            "x_exp_date"        => $card_exp_date,  
            "x_amount"          => $subscription_amount,
            //"x_credit_card_type" =>$cardcct,
            //"x_name_on_card"  =>$cardname,
            "x_first_name"      => $payment_first_name,
            "x_last_name"       => $payment_last_name,
            "x_address" => $payment_address01,
            "x_city" => $payment_city,
            "x_state" => $payment_state,
            "x_zip" => $payment_zipcode,
            "x_phone" => $payment_phone_number,
            "x_description" => 'Individual & Families',
            "x_email_customer" => "TRUE"        
        );
        $post_string = "";
        foreach( $post_values as $key => $value )
            { $post_string .= "$key=" . urlencode( $value ) . "&"; }
        $post_string = rtrim( $post_string, "& " );


            $request = curl_init($post_url); // initiate curl object
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); // use HTTP POST to send form data
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response.
            $post_response = curl_exec($request); // execute curl post and store results in $post_response
            // additional options may be required depending upon your server configuration
            // you can find documentation on curl options at http://www.php.net/curl_setopt
            curl_close ($request); // close curl object

        $response_array = explode($post_values["x_delim_char"],$post_response);
        $status_response = $response_array[0];
        $status_error = $response_array[3];
        if($status_response <> 1)
        {
         $response['error_msg']=$status_error;
         $response['pstatus']= 'FAILED';
        }
        else
        {
        $transaction_orderid = $response_array[6];
        $response['pstatus']= 'OK';     
        $response['transaction_id']= $transaction_orderid;
        }   
print json_encode($response);
```

Please help me to resolve this isssue.

ERROR THAT SHOWING ON LIVE AFTER TRANSACTION:

I looked at the receipt and everything seems fine but when I go into 
    authorize.net and check it out then it states 
    that it is voided out and amount shows $0.00.

Comment: What message? Please check your question.

Comment: Also, don't set test mode true in sandbox, it tells the gateway to only check the credentials and return success but not attempt a transaction.

Comment: Its working fine in text mode, but at live its giving error..

Comment: @mblaettermann issue updated in question please help me out on this

Comment: @rhldr should i true the request in live mode??

Comment: If you are testing in the sandbox, you should set test request to false.  Otherwise, it will only check credentials.  The transaction ID will be zero in test mode, another clue the gateway didn't actually process anything.

Comment: But transcation is going proper.. but its just showing voided in authorize.net panel.. every other things is working fine..